How did Popper combine his fallibilism with the idea that theories don’t have probabilities?
According to this accepted answer (unless it is simply incorrect),

For Popper, either a theory reflects 'reality' (scare quotes to note how ill-defined that word is), or it does not. There is no sense talking about whether a theory is probably true

But Popper was also a fallibilist.
As per the IEP,

Fallibilism is the epistemological thesis that no belief (theory, view, thesis, and so on) can ever be rationally supported or justified in a conclusive way.

But doesn’t the idea of “conclusive” justification involve some level of a degree of justification, where a theory, for example, may be partially but not conclusively justified? If so, does this not then imply a sort of “probability” (even in just an epistemic sense) of the theory being true?

Popper actually had a more extreme view of theories. He held that all theories have a probability of zero. Bear in mind he is using the term 'theory' here in a specific way to mean a universally and unrestrictedly quantified expression. So, for Popper, propositions such as, "A large meteorite colliding with the Earth at the end of cretaceous period contributed to the extinction of the dinosaurs" is not a theory because it is an existential claim. The conservation of linear momentum is a theory, but we can never conclusively confirm it because we can never observe all collisions of bodies.
In practice, Popper is somewhat equivocal when he speaks of probabilities. On a strict understanding of his falsificationist approach, a theory is never confirmed, justified or supported. All we can ever do is attempt to falsify it. If we fail to falsify it, that does not confirm, justify or support it.
However, Popper also speaks of 'corroboration' of theories, without specifying in detail what this means. A theory that has survived our best attempts to falsify it is better corroborated than a theory that has never been tested. But this sounds a lot like the confirmation of theories that advocates of confirmation theory propose.
Also, in a couple of papers published jointly with David Miller, Popper explicitly speaks of probabilistic support and uses a calculus that would be entirely familiar to a Bayesian. His claim is that probabilistic support is legitimate but it is deductive not inductive. There have been many responses challenging that position. But whether we characterise an inference as inductive or as probabilistic-deductive, Popper seems to be allowing that theories may have a probability.
K. Popper and D. W. Miller, A proof of the impossibility of inductive probability, Nature, 302, 687-688 (1983).
K. Popper and D. W. Miller, Why Probabilistic Support is not Inductive, Phil. Trans. Royal Society of London. A 321, 569-591 (1987).

The problem with Popper is that he was not really an epistemologist, though he considered himself one. If you compare his ideas with proper epistemology (Kant), you will find that Popper dogmatically postulates his falsification principle. He simply claims that all theories can never be definitively proven and that every theory must be falsifiable. Popper merely represents a practically useful and pragmatic stance, but he doesn’t offer much beyond that—hence, it doesn’t get you particularly far.


But doesn’t the idea of “conclusive” justification involve some level of a degree of justification, where a theory, for example, may be partially but not conclusively justified? If so, does this not then imply a sort of “probability” (even in just an epistemic sense) of the theory being true?

I don't think the probabilistic reading is the only possible reading. An alternative reading is that "conclusive" means "absolute certainity" as in a deductive logical proof, which we only see in mathematics and logic. However, even a logical "proof" relies on accepting the truth of the axioms and the truth-preserving nature of the inference rules with respect to the world (see If a conclusion logically follows from premises that are true in the world, will the conclusion also be true of the world?), which are assumptions you need to make that might also be wrong. In general, you always need to make assumptions that might be wrong (see Are two persons equally rational in choosing different dogmatic stopping points in their chains of justification as per the Münchhausen trilemma?).
For example, one key assumption in physics is that the world behaves regularly due to underlying principles or laws. However, it's possible that the world behaves randomly and we are just going through a very long happy streak of regular coincidences. So the past observed regularity doesn't make the hypothesis that there are laws more likely, the actual "probability" (if there is one) is just 0 (the hypothesis is false).
In general, jumping from "I need to make assumptions that might be wrong" to "my theory has a probability X of being true" seems to me to be an unjustified move.
